# Approximation to a product of sequence $\prod_{i=0}^{n}(1-\sigma i)$ when $\sigma$ is very small

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a formula I can use as an approximation to the following equation for velocity of a projectile when $\sigma$ is very small?

$$\dot{x}[n] =v_0\prod_{i=0}^{n}(1-\sigma i)$$
$$\sigma\approx\frac{C_1}{1,000,000};C_1\in[0,100]$$

I am trying to compute the distance travelled (programmatically) when it is shot with initial velocity $v_0$.

The sum would be:

$$x[n]=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dot{x}$$

or $$x[n]=v_0\sum_{j=0}^{n}\prod_{i=0}^{j}(1-\sigma i).$$

The solution for the sum according to a [wolfram alpha computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28product+%281-a%2ai%29%2C+i%3D0..j%29%2C+j%3D0..n) is very complicated and computationally expensive. I derived this formula from the following function which updates the velocity every tick (10 milliseconds).

```
fire() {
   frictiontimer = 1000000;
}

// This is called every 10ms
update() {
   if (xspeed) {
      int workfriction = frictiontimer / 1000;
      xspeed = xspeed * workfriction / 1000;

      frictiontimer -= FRICTION_CONSTANT;
      if (frictiontimer < 0)
         frictiontimer = 0;
   }
}
```

Is there is a simplification I can use somewhere?

Comment: Can you please use brackets like: $\prod (1 - \sigma i)$

Comment: Added, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $\sigma i$ is small, $1 - \sigma i \approx \exp(-\sigma i)$, so 
$$\prod_{i=0}^n (1 - \sigma i) \approx \exp \left( - \sum_{i=0}^n \sigma i \right) =
\exp(- \sigma n (n+1)/2)$$