# Result of the product $0.9 \times 0.99 \times 0.999 \times ...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, decimal-expansion

My question has two parts:

1. How can I nicely define the infinite sequence $0.9,\ 0.99,\ 0.999,\ \dots$? One option would be the recursive definition below; is there a nicer way to do this? Maybe put it in a form that makes the second question easier to answer. 
   $$s_{i+1} = s_i + 9\cdot10^{-i-2},\ s_0 = 0.9$$ 
   *Edit:* Suggested [by Kirthi Raman](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141705#comment326348_141705):
   $$(s_i)_{i\ge1} = 1 - 10^{-i}$$
2. Once I have the sequence, what would be the limit of the infinite product below? I find the question interesting since $0.999... = 1$, so the product should converge (I think), but to what? What is the "last number" before $1$ (I know there is no such thing) that would contribute to the product? 
   $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} s_i$$

Comment: How about $(1-\frac{1}{10})(1-\frac{1}{100})...= \prod_{i=0}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{10^i}) $

Comment: Your shorthand doesn't make sense. $0.9 \cdot 0.99 \cdot 0.999 \cdot \ldots$ makes sense as denoting an infinite product. $0.9 \cdot 0.99 \cdot 0.999 \cdot \ldots \cdot 0.9999999999999$ makes sense as denoting a finite product. The one you wrote doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KVRaman Thanks! :)

Comment: @Hurkyl I fixed the title.

Comment: $$s_i = 1-\frac1{10^i}$$

Comment: I've seen the corresponding product with powers of 2 instead of powers of 10 discussed somewhere. My recollection is that no simple expression in terms of well-known constants is known, nor is one expected, but I can't cite any references at the moment.

Comment: @PaulManta I changed the \cdots to \times because it was confusing with the numbers themselves with decimal values.

Comment: @PaulManta this converges to $0.89$, but you have to think how to show that.

Comment: @KVRaman in the product, i starts from 1 and not 0

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131012/approximation-to-a-product-of-sequence-prod-i-0n1-sigma-i-when-sigm) link provides a very decent approximation for your product.

Comment: @KV Raman: Pari/GP gives for 200 factors  0.8900100999989990000001000099999999899999 000000000010000009999999999998999999900000 000000000100000000999999999999999989999999 990000000000000000001000000000099999999999 9999999998999999999990000000000000... and this does not improve if we increase the number of factors.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha gives the following [result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Product%5B%281-10%5E%28-n%29%29,%7Bn,1,inf%7D%5D). Interestingly, its decimal expansion seems to consist solely of $0$'s, $1$'s, $8$'s and $9$'s. It does not look periodic, but otherwise seems to be quite regular, so it might be possible to prove nice properties about it.

Comment: @Tenali, I don't see the relation between the product in your link and the one in the current question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Approximate $1 - x$ with $e^{-x}$ just like Robert does in that link. The product becomes $e^{\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} -10^{-i}} = e^{-\frac{1}{9}} \sim 0.89$. Of course this approximation is not very great or anything.

Comment: Note that the fact that your factors converge to 1 is *necessary* for the product to converge, but it is not sufficient. There are products of sequences that converge to 1 that do not converge.

Comment: You can prove it converges because it is decreasing and bounded below by 0.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To elaborate, and extend on GEdgar's answer: there is what is called the [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html)

$$(a;q)_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-aq^k)$$

and $(a;q)_\infty$ is interpreted straightforwardly. The product you are interested in is equivalent to $\left(\frac1{10};\frac1{10}\right)_\infty\approx0.8900100999989990000001$.

One can also express the $q$-Pochhammer symbol $(q;q)_\infty$ in terms of the [Dedekind $\eta$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindEtaFunction.html) $\eta(\tau)$ or the [Jacobi $\vartheta$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) $\vartheta_2(z,q)$; in particular we have

$$\left(\frac1{10};\frac1{10}\right)_\infty=\sqrt[24]{10}\eta\left(\frac{i\log\,10}{2\pi}\right)=\frac{\sqrt[24]{10}}{\sqrt 3}\vartheta_2\left(\frac{\pi}{6},\frac1{\sqrt[6]{10}}\right)$$

---

I might as well... there is the following [identity, due to Euler](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=WfrqIv2a08gC&pg=PA7) (the *pentagonal number theorem*):

$$(q;q)_\infty=\prod_{j=1}^\infty(1-q^j)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^k q^\frac{k(3k-1)}{2}$$

which, among other things, gives you a series you can use for quickly estimating your fine product:

$$\left(\frac1{10};\frac1{10}\right)_\infty=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\left(10^{-\frac{k}{2}(3k+1)}+10^{-\frac{k}{2}(3k-1)}\right)$$

Three terms of this series gives an approximation good to twenty digits; five terms of this series yields a fifty-digit approximation.

Comment: No special function is too special for J.M.! :)

Answer (score 9):

By looking at the decimal representation, it appears that:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{10^i}\right)=
\sum_{i=1}^\infty
  \frac{8 +
    \frac{10^{2^i-1}-1}{10^{2i-1}} +
    \frac1{10^{6i-2}} +
    \frac{10^{4i}-1}{10^{12i-2}}
  }{10^{(2i-1)(3i-2)}}
$$

I don't have a proof, but the pattern is so regular that I'm confident.

Comment: «The pattern is so regular that I'm confident» are great last words! :D

Comment: Your formula follows from the Euler identity in J. M.'s answer.  In particular, every two terms in J. M.'s summation correspond to one term in your summation.

Comment: @WillOrrick: indeed. Now that J.M.'s answer contains this neat expression, my formula is an (increasing, though) abomination!

Comment: Ramanujan style.

Answer (score 4):

See: ["Dedekind eta function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function).

Comment: Isn't the [Euler function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function) more relevant?

Comment: And less well-known.  You can't even call it Euler's function phi, since that is something else...

Comment: For a series representation, see Euler's "pentagonal number theorem" ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem