# How to find the the product $\left(1 - \frac{1}{a}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{a^{2}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{a^{3}}\right)\ldots$

Tags: products

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Result of the product $0.9 \times 0.99 \times 0.999 \times \dots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141705/result-of-the-product-0-9-times-0-99-times-0-999-times)

How to find the product $$\left(1 - \frac{1}{a}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{a^{2}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{a^{3}}\right)\ldots$$ where $a>1$?
I tried opening the first few brackets and then then finding some pattern. Is there any shorter way? Thanks.

$PS$- This was a question in my textbook where $a = 5$ but I wanted to know a more general way.

Comment: It's not a particularly nice answer... see (46) and (47) on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem

Comment: Nice question. (+1)

Comment: Euler funcion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_function), which is a special case of the infinite q-Pochhammer Symbol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol