# Convergence of an infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty }(1-\frac1{2^k})$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

**Problem:**

I want to prove that the infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty }(1-\frac{1}{2^{k}})$ does not converge to zero. It doesn't matter to find the value to which this product converges, but I am still curious to know if anybody is able (if possible of course) to find the value to which this infinite product converges.  I appreciate any help. I tried the following trick: $\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_{k})\geq 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}$ which can be easily proven by inudction, where $a_{k}>-1$ and they are all positive or negative. In this case, $a_{k}=-\frac{1}{2^{k}}$, but I get : the infinite product is greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: You may want to take logarithm and then apply some sort of comparison to conclude that the resulting logarithmic sum converges. Then by exponentiation, you can find that the product converges to a positive number.

Comment: You can show via induction that $\prod_{k=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{2^k}) \ge \frac14 + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ and so in particular the infinite product converges to something that's at least $\frac14$.

Comment: @Alan Guo: How did you figure out your above inequaliy? I am just curious to see how you proved it.

Comment: @sos440: Can you, please, show me what kind of comparison you use to conclude convergence of the sum of the logarithms.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to prove using induction.

Comment: @C.Lambda, i'd like to, but I'm currently outside and I'm writing with my iPad. Typing TeX formulas with iPad is not far from a mental torture... And already many peoples are starting to post their own nice answers. I will post my answer when I'm available and still no satisfying answer at that moment.

Comment: This problem was also discussed at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776/limit-of-a-particular-variety-of-infinite-product-series).

Comment: See also: [Is the product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^k-1}{2^k}$ necessarily $0$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1322245/is-the-product-prod-k-1-infty-frac2k-12k-necessarily-0)

Comment: This is related, too: [What is the value of $\prod_{i=1}^\infty 1-\frac{1}{2^i}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200575/what-is-the-value-of-prod-i-1-infty-1-frac12i)
(Although that question asks about the exact value of the product, not only whether it diverges to zero.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose
$\prod_{k=1}^n (1-x^k) \ge a + x^{n+1}$
where $0 < x < 1$ and $0 < a < 1$.
Then
$\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} (1-x^k) 
\ge (a + x^{n+1})(1-x^{n+1})
= a + x^{n+1}(1-a)
$.

To make this $\ge a + x^{n+2}$,
we want $1-a \ge x$.
For $x = 1/2$, $a = 1/4$ will work.

So, this argument gives a basis for choosing values for $a$
that can makes this inequality true for this inductive proof.

Comment: I think you're missing a term... $(a+x^{n+1})(1-x^{n+1})$ should be $a+x^{n+1}(1-a-x^{n+1})$

Answer (score 2):

This question is almost identical to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141705/result-of-the-product-0-9-times-0-99-times-0-999-times).

In particular, while I wouldn't hope for a satisfying "closed form", [Euler's pentagonal number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) provides a simple expression for the binary expansion of this limit.

Answer (score 1):

From Taylor's Theorem with remainder, for $ 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}, $ we find
$$ -x - \frac{x^2}{2} \geq \log (1-x) \geq -x -2 x^2.   $$
because $$ f(x) = f(a) + f'(a) (x-a) + f''(\xi) \frac{(x-a)^2}{2}  $$ where
$\xi$ is between $x$ and $a.$

Your $x = \frac{1}{2^k}$ and $x^2 = \frac{1}{4^k}.$

Edddiiittt: now that I think of it, we could use Taylor's and stop at the linear term, $ -x  \geq \log (1-x) \geq -2x ,   $ still for $ 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}. $