# What is the value of $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\right)$?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Also, what about in general, for some value `p`, which has the value `2` in the given formula?

---

MOTIVATION:

I was wondering the probability of never getting `tails` if one forever flipped a coin whose probability of landing `tails` decreased (in this case, geometrically) each flip.

---

The probability of `tails` on flip `i` is $\frac{1}{2^i}$, and the probability of `heads` on flip `i` is $1-\frac{1}{2^i}$. So, first flip the coin is 50-50, next it is 75-25, etc. And the probability of never landing `tails` is equal to the probability of always landing `heads`, which is the infinite product of the `heads` probabilities, yielding $\prod_{i=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\right)$. => ($\frac{1}{2} * \frac{3}{4} * \frac{7}{8} ...$)

Comment: I don't think there's any analytic solution. The answer is approx 0.28878809

Comment: Why don't you think there's any analytic solution?

Also, might there be a very good approximation (besides the decimal approximation you provided, which I thank you for)? Like, a function that is very close to the partial products?

Comment: I just plugged it into Wolfram Alpha, and it gave the answer in terms of a Pochammer symbol. Just go there, type in "product 1-1/2^i from i=1 to infty" and you can get the answer to a huge number of decimal places.

Comment: Just to add, this number is also the measure of a (generalized) Cantor set, where we take the interval $[0,1]$ and then remove the middle half, and then remove the middle fourths from the two remaining intervals, and then remove the middle eights from the four remaining intervals, and so on...

Comment: Oooh, beautiful. That stuff is awesome. It is so cool that this is a non-zero constant. And any polynomial decrease (instead of exponential decrease) yields an infinite product equal to 0?

Comment: No, not true. The infinite product $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$ also converges to a nonzero number. In fact, $\Pi_i^{\infty} (1-a_i)$ converges to a nonzero number iff $\sum_i^{\infty} a_i < \infty$. (assuming all $a_i \in [0,1]$). Try to prove it (hint: use logarithms).

Comment: Ah woops, I also plugged into Wolfram, and saw 0, but to get a meaningful result I need to take product starting from i=2

Comment: Starting from i=1

Comment: 1-1/(n^2) is 0 when n is 1, so the whole product is 0, right?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were still talking about $1-1/2^i$. Yes, you're correct. Start from i=2. BTW, I meant to say $a_i \in [0,1)$ before, rather than $a_i \in [0,1]$.

Comment: See [OEIS A$048651$](http://oeis.org/A048651).

Comment: Well, after rereading the post, I have decided to retract my duplicate close vote - mainly because of the part asking about more general question about $\prod \left(1-\frac1p\right)$. (Although this is not addreseed in the answers.)

Comment: Lookup up "Euler function" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right) = -\sum_{k\geq 1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n 2^{kn}}=-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{d\mid m}\frac{1}{d}=-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\sigma_1(m)}{m 2^m}$$
hence:
$$\prod_{i\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^i}\right)=\exp\left(-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\sigma_1(m)}{m 2^m}\right)\geq\exp\left(-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{m+1}{2^{m+1}}\right)=e^{-3/2}$$
but the bound:
$$\sigma_1(m)=\sum_{d\mid m}d \leq \sum_{k=1}^{m}k = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$$
is obviously very crude.

Comment: You can just use $\log\left(1-2^{-k}\right)<-2^{-k}$ you get the simple upper bound for the probability is $e^{-1}.$

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [$q$-Pochhammer symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-Series.html) to represent the infinite product as

> $$ \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{2^i} \right) = \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \right)_{\infty} . $$

**Note:**

> $$ \left( a, q \right)_{\infty}= \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\left( 1-a q^k \right) $$

Comment: The $k$ in the last expression should be an $i?$