# Is there a closed form for 0.9 * 0.99 * 0.999 * ...?

Tags: closed-form, products

I'm trying to find a pretty closed form for:

$$0.9 \cdot 0.99\cdot 0.999 \cdots=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{10^n-1}{10^n}$$

The Nth partial product can be expressed as:

$$\frac{(10-1)(10^2-1)\cdots(10^N-1)}{10^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}$$

But it seems impossible to generalize the expansion of the numerator polynomial in 10.

Wolfram Alpha computes the following approximation:

$≈0.89001009999899900000010000999999998999990000000000100000099999999999989999999000000000000001000000009999999999999999899999999900000000$

Hence I strongly believe that a closed form exists.

Comment: It is $\phi(1/10)$ where $\phi(q)$ is [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function). See [Evaluate $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n-1}{2^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128456/evaluate-prod-n-1-infty-frac2n-12n)

Comment: The regularity you see in the decimal expansion is related to the [Euler identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function#Properties), also known as the [pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem):
$$\phi(q)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n q^{(3n^2-n)/2}\;.$$