# How to calculate infinite product of $(2^n-1)/2^n$??

Tags: real-analysis, infinite-product

How to calculate infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(2^n-1)/2^n$
i.e. $(1-1/2)(1-1/4)(1-1/8)(1-1/16) \cdots $

I know the value is around $0.2888 \cdots$ but I can't figure out how the number come.

If the answer is so complicated, anyone could explain me how to show that the value doesn't converge to $0$?

thanks.

Comment: Now I see convergence value is strictly positive.

Comment: I have voted to close this as the primary question asked is an exact duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128456/evaluate-prod-n-1-infty-frac2n-12n, which itself has been linked to 3 more exact duplicates https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1200575

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: To answer the last part,
just note that $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2^{n}} <\infty$. Hence $\log \prod_1^{N} \frac {2^{n}-1} {2^{n}}=\log \prod_1^{N} (1- \frac  1 {2^{n}})=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \log (1-\frac 1 {2^{n}})$. Now use the fact that $\frac {log (1-x)} x \to -1$ as $x $ increases to $0$. Can you finish the proof now?

Answer (score 2):

This product is related to the [Dedekind eta-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function). Indeed for
$|q|<1$, Euler's pentagonal number formula states that
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^n)=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k(q^{k(3k-1)/2}+q^{k(3k+1)/2}).$$
The sum has the advantage over the product of being more rapidly convergent.

A general result on infinite products is that if $(a_n)$ is a sequence
with $0<a_n<1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, then $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-a_n)$ converges to a strictly positive value. This proves your product
must be positive.

Comment: Please my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128456/evaluate-prod-n-1-infty-frac2n-12n/2128460#2128460 presenting the same rapidly convergent series as well as proof of transcendence.