# Infinite product involving powers of 2

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I have the following infinite product:

$2/1 * 3/2 * 5/4 * 9/8 * 17/16 * 33/32 * 65/64...$

What does it converge to?

I can take its $\ln()$ to get

$\ln(2) + \ln(3/2) + \ln(5/4)....$

Which using the quotient difference rule resolves to

$S(n) = \ln(2^n + 1) - n\ln(2)$ for $n = 0$ to $\infty$

At this point I don't know how to evaluate this: so I took its derivative to see if I could recognize anything:

$S'(n) = 2^n * ln(2) / (2^n + 1) - ln(2)$

Which really looks like it converges to 0...

Integrating $S(n)$ hasn't been much to avail unless its because I lack knowledge.

What's this come out to?

Comment: Wolfram alpha [gives an exact evaluation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+of+%282%5En+%2B+1%29%2F2%5En+for+n+%3D+0+to+n+%3D+infinity).

Comment: [A related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141705)

Comment: @JavaMan: Really? When I follow your link I get only an approximation.

Comment: @Henning: Oops, you are correct.  I meant that there is an exact evaluation for the partial product.  Turning that exact evaluation into an exact evaluation for the infinite product looks highly nontrivial, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the first term for a moment.

$$
\frac{3}{2}\frac{5}{4}\cdots\frac{2^k+1}{2^k}\cdots = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1 + \frac{1}{2^k}) 
$$

When the product is expanded, what is the coefficient of $\frac{1}{2^n}$? A term comes from any number of distinct factors of the form $\frac1{2^k}$.  And so, each partition

$$
n = k_1 + k_2 + \cdots + k_m
$$

provides a term in the $\frac{1}{2^n}$.  So, the product is:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{q(n)}{2^n}
$$

where $q(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct integers. I don't think this has a closed form.

Answer (score 1):

There is no nice answer to this. Here is a way to approximate it.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \ln\left(1+\dfrac1{2^n}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1} \dfrac{1}{k2^{kn}} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}k \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{2^{kn}} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}k \dfrac{2^k}{2^k-1} \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

4.768462058062755

According to Wolfram Alpha.  Look it up it is explained there.

Comment: This is better as a comment as it is not instructive as an actual solution to the OP.