# Convergence of infinite product of prime reciprocals?

Tags: number-theory, limits, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, infinite-product

Where p<sub>n</sub> is the n<sup>th</sup> prime number, does the infinite product
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_n}\right)$$
converge to a nonzero value? (Any help would be much appreciated!)

Comment: What does the few expanded product to series look like?

Comment: Since $ \left(1-\frac{1}{p_n}\right) \lt  1 $ we have that $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right) \lt 1  \;\; \forall n \in \Bbb N$$

Comment: In case of infinite products they do not converge to zero, they diverge to zero

Comment: Arjang and @Ishfaaq: infinite products all of whose terms are between zero and one CAN converge to non-zero values. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141705/result-of-the-product-0-9-times-0-99-times-0-999-times for an example...

What I am asking here is if $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_n}\right)>0$$

But, as of Liu Gang's answer, it appears that  $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_n}\right)=0 \text{ since } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_n} diverges $$ so it does in fact converges to zero

Comment: @ManRow : I was aware of that example, there was a comment that contained "convergence to 0" in case of infinite products that is no correct, they only diverge to 0.

Comment: The question has already been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588369/infinite-product-involving-primes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all $a_n \in (0,1)$, $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty} (1- a_n)$ is non-zero if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n < +\infty$

And we know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{p_n} = +\infty$, you can find proofs [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes)

Comment: See [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) for more details.