# Why is $0$ the $0^\text{th}$ prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976415/convergence-of-infinite-product-of-prime-reciprocals) on $\prod_{n\to \infty}(1-1/p_n)$, played a little at [Wolfram's Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427epj1s7ubiug) and found the following:

The series expansion of a related indefinite integral $\int \log (1-1/p_n)dn$ gave a series expansion at $n=0$ of

$$
n \log(1-1/p_0)+O(n^2)+\text{constant}
$$

I continued and asked W|A what the [$0^\text{th}$ prime](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e501bned049) is and got 
$$
p_0 = -\sqrt{10} \lfloor \sqrt{10}\alpha\rfloor +\lfloor 10^1 \alpha\rfloor \tag{*}
$$
for [$\alpha = \sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k/10^{2^k}\approx 0.0203001$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427etbelevaven). So $p_0=0$. Fine (for the moment), but where does $(*)$ come from?

Comment: This is obtained by considering identity $(*)$, valid for every integer $n\geqslant1$, out of its range of validity. (Oh... and zero is not prime.)

Comment: $0$ is not a prime but $(0)$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$