# Product of Primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, products

Let $\mathbb{P}$ denote the set of prime numbers. How would one evaluate
$$\prod_{p\in \mathbb{P}}\frac{p-1}{p}$$ I do not think that the fact that $$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$$ can be applied, but it is worth noting. Additionally, if we take the log, we obtain
$$\log\left(\prod_{p\in \mathbb{P}}\frac{p-1}{p}\right)=\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\log\left(\frac{p-1}{p}\right)=\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\log(p-1)-\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\log(p)$$

Comment: How do you get $\Pi_{n=2}^\infty\frac{n-1}{n}=0$?  Not obvious to me.

Comment: Take the log, and use the fact (Euler) that $\sum \frac{1}{p}$ diverges.

Comment: You might want to check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function. The $\zeta(1)$ diverges (goes to $\infty$) and it seems to be reciprocal of what you try to evaluate, so your product should converge to $0$.

Comment: $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{n}$ looks something like $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{3}{4} \times...$. We can cancel out the top of each fraction with the bottom of the previous fraction in order to see that this is equal to just $\frac{1}{n}$, which approaches 0 when $n$ approaches infinity.

Comment: I think I have found a duplicate [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588369/infinite-product-involving-primes). The answers there use stronger results, but also prove that $\sum_p \frac{1}{p}$ diverges.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, I think what the OP meant is $\prod_{n=2}^\infty{n-1\over n}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=2}^N{n-1\over n}=\lim_{N\to\infty}{1\over N}=0$.  I.e., it's a "telescoping" product.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks Barry, that helps

Comment: to prove that $\prod (1-1/p) = 0$ you have to prove that $\sum_p 1/p = \infty$ and the simplest way is with $\ln \zeta(s) = \sum_p \sum_{r=1}^\infty \displaystyle \frac{p^{-sr}}{r}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $Re(s)> 1$ we have the Euler product
$$
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\prod_p (1-p^{-s}).
$$
Taking the limit $s\to 1$ shows that the infinite product $\prod_p (1-\frac{1}{p})$ is $0$, since $\lim_{s\to 1}\zeta(s)=\infty$.

A second possibility is to use that
the product $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1- a_n)$ is non-zero if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty$, provided $a_i\in (0,1)$. 
But since $\sum_p\frac{1}{p}=\infty$, taking $a_i=\frac{1}{p_i}$ gives that the infinite product is zero.

Comment: How is $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\prod_{p}\frac{p-1}{p}$?

Comment: Because of the [Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product) for $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think Romain has noticed that the power $s$ is missing.

Comment: I think one would usually not say 'converges to 0'.  Usually convergence of an infinite product is to a nonzero finite value.  See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product

Comment: @paw88789 corrected.

Comment: to prove that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \prod_{p \le N} (1-1/p) = \lim_{s \to 1^+} 1/\zeta(s) = 0$ you have to rely on the fact that $1/p > 0$ and that $\zeta$ has a (meromorphic) pole there

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Mertens' 3rd theorem which states that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log n\prod_{p\le n}\left(1-\frac1p\right)=e^{-\gamma}\;.
$$