# A totient-like function relating to twin pairs

Tags: totient-function, twin-primes, primorial

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3248027/) Larry Freeman showed that $\prod_1^n(p_i-2)$ reports the number of pairs of numbers $x,(x+2)$ such that $x<p_n\# \wedge \gcd (x(x+2),p_n\#)=1$.

This bears a striking resemblance to Euler's totient function applied to primorials, which states $\phi(p_n\#)=\prod_1^n(p_i-1)$ and reports the number of numbers $x$ such that $x<p_n\# \wedge \gcd (x,p_n\#)=1$. More generally, for $x=\prod(p_i^{a_i})$, the totient $\phi(x)=\prod(p_i^{a_i-1})(p_i-1)$.

I was curious to see whether Freeman's observation could be generalized, and looking at a small number of examples, I formulated a totient-like function which I denote $\phi_2(x)$: 
$$\phi_2(2)=1\\
\phi_2(p)=(p-2);\ p>2\in \mathbb P\\
\phi_2(2^a)=2^{a-1}\\
\phi_2(p^a)=p^{a-1}(p-2)$$
The function is multiplicative:
$$\phi_2(m)\cdot \phi_2(n)=\phi_2(mn) \text{ when }\gcd(m,n)=1$$
This totient-like function seems to report the number of numbers $n$ smaller than $x$ such that $\gcd (n(n+2),x)=1$. Note that $n+2$ need not be smaller than $x$; the pair $(x-1),(x+1)$ is counted by this function.

**Questions:** 1. Have I reinvented a well known wheel? I could not find anything about a function of this sort in a quick search of Wikipedia topics. Any references or citations would be appreciated. 2. The properties of the function I have observed are based on counting/computation for a small number of examples. Is it possible to **prove** that $\phi_2(x)$ in fact reports $n<x$ such that $\gcd (n(n+2),x)=1$?

Comment: Is the function $\phi_2(x)$ the same as https://oeis.org/A002472?

Comment: Re question 2: Yes, it is possible to prove that. There are $(p-2)p^{m-1}$ residue classes modulo $p^m$ for which $p \nmid n(n+2)$. Now apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @Steven Clark Yes it is! Thanks for the link.