# Finding the limit of a subset of natural numbers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I was asked a question by one of my friends that seemed interesting however, I don't know how to start.

the question is that for any real number $a \in [0,1]$, show that there is a subsequence of number in $\mathbb{N}$, such that:

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\phi(m_n)}{m_n}=a.
$$

I know that this limit is equivalent to show that for any $a \in [0,1]$, we want to show that:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \prod_{i=1} \left( 1- \frac{1}{p_{in}} \right)=a
$$
$p_{in}$ is the $i^{th}$ prime divisor $m_n$.

Comment: Hint: try a greedy algorithm.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976415/convergence-of-infinite-product-of-prime-reciprocals) might be helpful.