# How to compute the infinite product?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Given the following infinite product:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\cdots \frac{2^n-1}{2^n}.$$

It is easy to see that above infinite product is convergent by the convergence of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln \left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$$.

But I do not know how to calculate the infinite product. I would appreciate it if someone can give any suggestions and comments.

Comment: Are your denominators the even numbers from 2 to $2^n$ ?? or the powers of $2$ from $2^1$ to $2^n$ ??  I assume the second, but you cannot tell by looking at the formula with the $\cdots$.

Comment: @GEdgar: It has to be the second, if you look at the explicit summation that follows.

Comment: If it is powers of $2$ ... Find lots of information on this (and the assertion that no closed form is known) at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/141757/442 which deals with the corresponding infinite product with powers of $10$.

Answer (score 1):

For the infinite product
$$P=\frac{\prod_{i=0}^\infty (2^i-1) } {\prod_{i=0}^\infty 2^i }=\frac{315}{1024}\frac{\prod_{i=5}^\infty (2^i-1) } {\prod_{i=5}^\infty 2^i }$$

$$A=\log \left(\frac{\prod_{i=5}^\infty (2^i-1) } {\prod_{i=5}^\infty 2^i } \right)=\sum_{i=5}^\infty\log \left(1-\frac1 {2^i}\right)=-\sum_{i=5}^\infty \Big[\frac1 {2^i}+ \frac1 {2^{2i}}+\frac1 {2^{3i}}+\cdots\Big]$$ and we face geometric progressions. So, summing up to infinty, we have
$$A=-\Big[\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{768} +\frac{1}{28672}+\frac{1}{983040}+\frac{1}{32505856}+\frac{1}{1056964608}+\cdots\Big]$$ Using only these numbers
$$A \sim -\frac{10458550091}{163829514240}$$ Now using the approximation
$$e^A=\frac{1+\frac{A}{2}+\frac{A^2}{12}}{1-\frac{A}{2}+\frac{A^2}{12}}=\frac{311910183016998882664441}{332471213189757736214521}$$
$$P=\frac{98251707650354648039298915}{340450522306311921883669504}$$ which, converted to decimals is
$P=0.28859$ while the "exact" value is $P=0.28879$

Answer (score 0):

You maybe could simplify the denominator of the infinite product since $\prod_{n=1}^{m}2^n=2^{\sum_{n=1}^{m}n}=2^{\frac{m(m+1)}{2}}$ which would mean that $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{n=1}^{m}\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}=\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2^{\frac{m(m+1)}{2}}} \prod_{n=1}^{m}(2^n-1)$